# Can't start gdb.exe in Qt Creator

Tags: c++, debugging, qt, gdb

I have a project in Qt Creator that builds fine, but when I try to debug it I get this message:

```
Adapter start failed
Unable to start gdb 'C:\Qt\2010.02.1\mingw\bin\gdb.exe':
Process failed to start: The directory name is invalid
```

If I navigate to the debug build folder and directly run my compiled application, it will run fine, but obviously there's no debugging support. Additionally, gdb.exe is present at C:\Qt\2010.02.1\mingw\bin\gdb.exe, but Qt Creator can't seem to run it. How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tools->Options->Debugger->Gdb
From
Gdb location you can set the path to your preferred GBD.

Comment: Relevant link: [Qt Creator bug report: Debugger fails to start, gdb executable not found](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-16211)

Answer (score 7):

I've had the same error, despite gdb **did** exist in the specified path and started without errors from command line. It turned out that the **Working directory** in the project settings didn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

use: "C:\Qt\2010.02.1\mingw\bin\gdb.exe"

Comment: I know that I can debug from the command line, but is there any way to get it working in Qt Creator?

Comment: I mean, found where configure the path, and add " , windows may have some error on process the path with ./\

Comment: In QtCreator 3.1.1, it is in Tools->Options->Build & Run->Debuggers